# Using limit flag with ansible-playbook causes localhost to not be found

Tags: ansible

I am running ansible playbook with the limit flag.

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts --vault-password-file /etc/hostname playbooks/install.yml --tags "printa" --limit 'all:!vm'
```

but this causes localhost to be not found:

```
PLAY [Playing with Ansible and Git] *****************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************************************
.
.
```

This is my `install.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: "Playing with Ansible and Git"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local 
  tasks:

  - name: "just execute a ls -lrt command"
    shell: "ls -lrt"
    register: "output"

  - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansible [implicit localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html#implicit-localhost) is not part of the `all` (nor any other...) group.

You either need to:

- add `localhost` explicitly to your inventory. But it will then match the `all` group in your playbooks too with all undesired possible effects
- add that localhost to your limit which would be my preferred option here:

  ```
  --limit 'localhost:all:!vm'
  ```